# Interfacing PIC32MZ Microcontroller with Microphones

Tags: microcontroller, usb, audio, microchip, microphone

Microcontroller: PIC32MZ2048EFH144 (10 Bit ADC)

Software this runs on: MPLABX

Datasheet: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/60001191G.pdf

This Microphone has a built in USB port. My goal is to interface 3-4+ USB microphones using some USB hub with this microcontroller and receive data and do analysis.

However, since the USB microphones have their own certain range ADC, which is different from the USB port ADC, I would assume I would run into issues when it comes to getting data from the microphones when connecting multiple microphones to that one ADC channel through some USB Hub.

My question essentially is, how do I figure out what USB microphone would be ideal case in this situation? What are the tradeoffs and things that may cause an issue later on regarding connecting multiple microphones?

I had potentially thought of looking into the Blue SnowFlake Condenser Microphone. Has a 16 Bit ADC

Link for microphone: http://cd.bluemic.com.s3.amazonaws.com/pdf/snowball/manual.pdf

Comment: Why do you want to connect USB microphones to the PIC? A better solution could be to use regular microphones and digitise them with the PIC.

Comment: I wanted to take the approach of not using any circuitry. I do have ECM microphones but i would need to implement a pre-amplifier, etc. Wanted to stay away from extra hardware material. Is this what you mean? I wanted to simply find a USB microphone that would be able to connect to the microcontroller.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, and you've come to a valid conclusion :)

Comment: Hm, well.... I will do more research then to find USB microphones then. If not, I guess I can take the analog circuitry route -___-

Answer (score 0):

You don't use an ADC in the microcontroller to connect to USB microphones. USB is already purely digital. You need a USB host or OTG controller <s>and as far as I can see from the linked datasheet, that PIC doesn't have it.</s>

Just won't work.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that the PIC32MX doesn't support USB Microphones? Is the USB host controller a seperate module i can integrate here or would I have to look into a new microController?

Comment: It's unlikely you'd be able to connect one to the PIC. Look for one with a USB host or OTG controller. No ADC is needed on the host.

Comment: But I just looked through the PIC datasheet and it shows that it supports OTG?   "The Universal Serial Bus (USB) module contains
analog and digital components to provide a USB 2.0
embedded host, device, or OTG implementation with a
minimum of external components."

Comment: The 32MZ is able to function as a host. I don't know what device class the microphones are, but they're probably isochronous. I suspect there would be a reasonable amount of driver work required for the PIC.

Comment: I am sorry. I missed the USB section on the front page of the datasheet. Yes, that PIC will work, though the built-in ADC is still irrelevant.